# Java Reflection - get the name of a field from a set method

Tags: java, reflection, field, setter

i started to work with java reflection I started to create my own personal working methods, including a method that takes all the setter of a class.
Now I find myself in the bizarre situation of wanting to take the name of the field of methods set, i try to make myself more clear with a example:

```
private String urla;
public setUrl(String urlb){
   this.urla = urlb;
}
```

I have now a method for get the Method "setUrl" and i want create a method for take the field of the set method that is initialized from it, like this:

```
Mehtod method = getSetter(); //return method setUrl
String nameField = getFieldFromSetter(method) //return "urla"
```

You think it's possible? ty in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: This is possible only if you call it `setUrla` instead of `setUrl`.

Comment: If you name the setter properly `setUrla` you could just replace `set` with null and find a field that equals the resulting name `Urla` (but not case-sensitive). BUT you could save the current value of every variable (in a hashmap), call the function, create a new map for all variables, compute changes between the maps and reset the variable(s). (This could not work as other threads could modify the variable or access them at the same time, but otherwise it should be fine. Also, it's more of a hack than a good method :) )

Comment: The whole purpose of having getters/setter is to abstract the work they do. I.e. unless the setter follows some *additional* constraint it is not even correct to assume it writes to a field (or to one field only). Or that it has no additional effects and so on.

Comment: I think the closest you can do is get the name of the parameter `urlb`, or get the name from the method name, like others mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the field matches the name of the setter.  In this way you can induce the name of the field from the setter by convention.

If you need to find the actual field set, you need to examine the byte code.  You can obtain the byte code of the class from the class loader and visit this byte code with library like ASM and determine the name of the field it sets.  Note: this is a lot harder than following a convention.

Another approach is to add an annotation to the setter from which you can obtain the name of the field set.

Comment: Yes, is seem these  are the only way, and ASM is a good choice.